# Is valid HTML important past pageload?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I read an article that suggested working around a method that is not strictly valid (`target="_blank"`) by applying the rules after pageload via javascript.

That strikes me as a large case of using the letter of the law to defeat the spirit of the law, but I don't want to criticize before knowing if it's really a problem. Is there something about code validation that makes it only matter before any scripts have executed?

Comment: `target="_blank"` is valid under HTML5, so you could just switch your doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make your page as valid as possible. You don't make it valid for W3, but for your users. Invalid HTML needs to be corrected by the browser to be displayed. Every browser may do this differently, so invalid markup may (theoretically) result in your page looking different in each browser.

If you add the markup from JavaScript, it will be just as invalid and it gives you the same risk. The only thing you did, is trick the W3 validator, because it won't execute the Javascript. So in fact, it tests another page than your users will see. If you do that, your validation is useless.

That said, I believe `target="_blank"` works in most any browser, so if you really need it, and can't change the doc type, well, you'll just have to live with that one error you get from the validator.

And then again, the markup itself looks ok (no omitted elements, everything is nicely escaped and quotes), so it's just a single attribute that may be ignored by the browser. Worst case, the browser will ignore the target. Theoretically a browser could fail to render the page, but in this case that is very unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

I can't se that there are any reasons beyond being able to pass validation tests. If you don't care about those errors, it is just as correct (or incorrect) to include them without javascript.

I personally belive that if you need to do `target="_blank"`, just embed it in the html on page load and don't rely on JS do accomplish it, that seems just silly.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a lot of javascript errors disappear by fixing invalid markup. Anything that must parse the page (javascript, css, etc) will benefit from valid markup. I've watched other developers work on js problems for hours, cursing IE and browser differences, only to come behind them and fix the problem by fixing the markup and deleting their IE-only script crap.

So, yes, I think valid markup is very important.

I think the most important markup is having valid hierarchies - closing divs and over tags properly. The target attribute probably isn't going to screw you up, but I'd say do it right anyway. When you start adding exceptions to the rules, you're on a slippery slope.